# IEnumerable.Cast<T> throws InvalidCastException on type that supports cast

Tags: c#, generics, ienumerable

[IEnumerable.Cast](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.cast?view=netframework-4.7.2) should cast an IEnumerable of some type to type T.

I have a type that has an implicit cast from string.

```cs
public class MyType
{
    private string _value;

    private MyType(string value)
    {
        _value = value;
    }

    public static implicit operator MyType(string value)
    {
        return new MyType(value);
    }
}
```

A simple unit test show the type is castable from string.

```cs
[TestMethod]
public void CastSucceeds()
{
    string s = "123";
    var mt = (MyType)s;

    Assert.IsInstanceOfType(mt, typeof(MyType));
}
```

Just calling `Cast<T>` runs wihtout error.

```cs
[TestMethod]
public void IEnumerableCastSeemsToSucceed()
{
    IEnumerable<string> strings = new List<string> { "Foo", "Bar" };
    var myTypes = strings.Cast<MyType>();

    Assert.IsInstanceOfType(myTypes, typeof(IEnumerable<MyType>));
}
```

But when I actually enumerate I get a InvalidCastException.

```cs
[TestMethod]
public void IEnumerableCastToListFails()
{
    IEnumerable<string> strings = new List<string> { "Foo", "Bar" };
    var myTypes = strings.Cast<MyType>();

    var list = myTypes.ToList();

    Assert.IsInstanceOfType(list, typeof(List<MyType>));
}
```

```
Test failed: IEnumerableCastToListFails Duration: 13,00ms
Failure:
System.InvalidCastException : Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'MyType'.
Stack Trace:
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.d__97`1.MoveNext()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at IEnumerableCastToListFails()
```

I don't understand why I get that exception. My first test proves we *are* able to cast System.String to Mytype. Did I misunderstand the possibilities of IEnumerable.Cast? How can I solve this?

Update: My question has been marked as duplicate, but the questions mentioneded regard conversion from int to long. The anwswers talk about boxing and unboxing. That does not seem to be the case in my situation I think. Both `string` and `MyType` are reference types, so boxing should not occur. I think it would help if someone will supply an answer why `Cast<T>` does not work for custom types which have a cast operator implemented.

Comment: Note that `Cast<T>` is lazy so it doesn't actually do any casting until you iterate the result.

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski `OfType` would just return an empty list since `string` is not derived from `MyType`.

Comment: Yep, known behaviour. `Cast` uses generics - internally it does `(T)obj`. Generic casts don't take account of user-defined types conversions, they just do reference conversions and boxing/unboxing. You need to do `.Select(x => (MyType)x)`, that way the compiler knows at compile-time that `MyType` is involved in the cast, and can find the appropriate user-defined type conversion

Comment: Part of the problem is that the syntax `(T)x` can mean many different things, depending on what `T` and `x` are. [Here's a list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/conversions#explicit-conversions). Only some of those things are supported when generics get involved.

Comment: The source, for those interested: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/d9ba7001/src/libraries/System.Linq/src/System/Linq/Cast.cs#L52 - the docs for Cast specifically call out this limitation: "*The only type conversions that are performed by this method are reference conversions and unboxing conversions.* The runtime type of the elements in the collection must match the target type, or in the case of value types, the runtime type of elements must be the result of a boxing conversion of the target type. Other conversion types, such as those between different numeric types, are not allowed."

Comment: @canton7 You might want to provide an answer in stead of a comment.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I closed this as a duplicate -- looks like it's been reopened. The duplicates I found had good-quality answers: no point in providing yet another one.

Comment: A conversion from int -> long is treated exactly the same as a user-defined type conversion as far as generics are concerned (the difference is that it's defined in the language spec, rather than in the runtime, but that's an implementation detail of the compiler as far as you're concerned). The duplicates were correct, re-opening this was not.